# I am unable to successfully use my css file in my django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-staticfiles

```
[03/May/2021 11:44:59] "GET /add_food/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4583
[03/May/2021 11:44:59] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1763
[03/May/2021 11:45:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3812
[03/May/2021 11:45:04] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1763
[03/May/2021 11:46:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3812
[03/May/2021 11:46:24] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1763
[03/May/2021 11:48:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3812
[03/May/2021 11:48:07] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1763
```

This is the error I am facing on running the server and reloading the localhost.

the part where I have added my static file is as follows

```
<link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

where i have defined static in settings.py is as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_saved')
```

my project structure is linked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlUTf.png)

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is  `django.contrib.staticfiles` included in `INSTALLED_APPS`? Have you tried replacing `static_saved` by `static` in `STATIC_ROOT`?

Comment: check your `DEBUG`in `settings.py` file it should be `True `

Comment: Did you add {% load static %} at the top in your HTML file? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Elaborate is DEBUG=True or False, show your folder structure and urls.py